# LLM context windows: canonical source?

Tags: large-language-model

I am trying to build my own LLM driven chatbot, without the use of Langchain, LlamaIndex or other modules. One of the things one needs to account for is the context window of the LLM, so the user is aware they are reaching the limit beyond which the LLM forgets the beginning of their conversation.

Having tried the info pages on Huggingface with very limited success, I am turning to you: where can I find the context windows for Open Source LLMs?

I have looked on Huggingface and at best, it's hit or miss: sometimes there is mention of context window, most often there isn't.

Google will help on occasion, but its results are mostly unusable.

Answer (score 0):

for posterity's sake, I'll post the answer myself :)

say you want to run OpenHermes-2.5-Mistral-7B. you go to the canonical Huggingface page, then navigate to Files. There, find config.json—open it.

glance over all the technobabble and look for "max_position_embeddings". in this example, it is 32768 ("32k").